# $\{ (-1)^n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ "converges" to two values: $\pm1$

Tags: real-analysis

What is this property called? I can't remember it.

Here is the definition:

**Let $\left\{a_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a complex or real sequence. $a$ is called a ______ for $\left\{a_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ if for all $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists infinite many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|a_n-a| <\epsilon$.**

Fill in the blank :D

Kind regards

Comment: Are you thinking about the $\limsup$ and the $\liminf$? Your $\limsup$ is $1$ and your $\liminf$ is $-1$.

Comment: @JuliusL33t I will add the definition!

Comment: Seems like you are looking for limit points of a sequence.

Comment: You are right! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your sequence converges along (at least) 2 subsequences. As far as I know there is no specific name for that behaviour. Here the two obvious subsequences are $n = 2k$ and $n = 2k +1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

The limits of the convergent subsequences are called **accumulation points**.

Comment: I will add the definition!

Comment: In that case $a$ is called an **accumulation point** of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Why not improve your answer using your comment?

Comment: Good idea, thanks!